# Making a quote roller with buttons and timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, quotes

We're trying to make a quote roller with buttons and a timer. We have gotten pretty far, but at this point the buttons won't work correctly here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaXXg/1/

and here are the codes

```
var quotes = [
    "Quote1<br><br>  -  Repomeri",
    "Quote2 <br><br> - Emmi",
    "Quote3<br><br> - Taateli",
    "Quote4<br><br> - Joonas",
    "Quote5<br><br> - Eskelinen",
];

var i = 0;
var timer = null;

setInterval(function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    if (i == quotes.length) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}, 4 * 1000);


var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'),
    b2 = document.getElementById('b2'),
    b3 = document.getElementById('b3'),
    b4 = document.getElementById('b4'),
    b5 = document.getElementById('b5');


b1.onclick = function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    i = 0;
};

b2.onclick = function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    i = 1;
};

b3.onclick = function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    i = 2;
};

b4.onclick = function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    i = 3;
};

b5.onclick = function() {
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
    i = 4;
};
```

Comment: You can simplify your code since you are using jQuery already. See my updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/BaXXg/8/ You last 30 lines of codes could actually be written in 3 lines in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put the assignment to `i` before calling `html(quotes[i])`. For example:

```
b1.onclick = function() {
    i = 0;
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the variable `i` before the `$("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);`.

you could also use `class` and reduce your code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="b1">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="b2">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="b3">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="b4">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="b5">
```

JS:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    i = $(this).attr('id').substr(1);
    i--;
    $("#slideContainer").html(quotes[i]);   
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BaXXg/5/)